# run Smartgit in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, 13.04, scripts

I have downloaded a Smartgit 4.5.5 and trying to use in Ubuntu 13.04. But the problem is when i double click on the script smartgithg.sh it opens on the Gedit. On the previous versions of ubuntu i did not face this issues.

In the previous versions, when i double click on the script it shows me few options like 'Run', 'Run in terminal', 'Close' and so on.

here i would like to mention that the execution permission is enabled for this script. and i can run the script via terminal.

Comment: I have written the installation steps in my blog.                        http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/03/install-uninstall-smartgit-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually SmartGit is releasing .deb packages which is easy to install than the other packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my blog post [here](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/06/Ubuntu-13-04-Execute-scripts-on-double-click.html) suggests

1. Open file explorer `Files`.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and select `Preferences`.
3. It would show something like this.

   [image]
4. In the `Behavior` tab, select `Run executable text files when they are opened` and close it.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth knowing that Smartgit can be installed on ubuntu - I heavily use it in Ubuntu 13.04 and 14.04 - like it was a native app (as it was installed from the Software Center).

In fact, in the same folder where you find `smartgithg.sh` you can find `add-menuitem.sh`. To install Smartgit you can run it *once* by doing:

- `cd smartgithg-4_5_5/bin`
- `sudo ./add-menuitem.sh`

After that you can find Smartgit in the unity list of programs (just type <kbd>Super</kbd> and write "Smartgit"), and you can add it on the launcher.

This type of installation has also the advantage that Smartgit downloads and install the last version automatically when an update comes out, so you don't need to uninstall and re-install the new version anymore.

If you want to remove Smartgit run the commands:

- `cd smartgithg-4_5_5/bin`
- `sudo ./remove-menuitem.sh`

and remove the folder `smartgithg-4_5_5`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: from the previous answer, no i know what was the reason of the changed behavior and i liked this solutions and using this way. thanks

Comment: The auto-update feature also works when launching `bin/smartgithg.sh` directly.

Comment: It works for ubuntu 14.04. Thanks you.