# how can I put a button on the desktop to shutdown pc?

Tags: shutdown

how can I put a button on the desktop to shutdown pc? I use Ubuntu 13.04 with unity.
Thank you for a help

Comment: Why not just hit the power button?

Comment: Or select shutdown from the top right gear icon?

Comment: You can also use the HUD by writing "*Shutdown*"'s translation into it and then select the option to do this.

Answer (score 5):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - Opens the terminal
2. `touch ~/Desktop/Shutdown.sh && chmod 755 ~/Desktop/Shutdown.sh` - Creates Shutdown.sh and sets execute permission
3. `gedit ~/Desktop/Shutdown.sh` - Opens the file in gedit.
4. Copy and Paste the following line in gedit

   ```
   pkexec shutdown -P -h now
   ```
5. Save the file and close gedit.
6. As per this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309613/run-smartgit-in-ubuntu-13-04/309715#309715), make sure that you can execute executable files.
7. Now double click on `Shutdown.sh` file in the desktop. It would show something like this and enter the password.

[image]

It should shutdown your machine now.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without having to authenticate every time you want to switch off the device?